# Azure app insight and debugging VS 2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-application-insights

As soon as I add Application Insights for Azure using Visual studio 2013 I can no longer debug the website using f5 it just keeps spinning showing a white page and never loads. Does anybody know why or how to fix?

I am running VS with update 4

Comment: no errors?  if you do break all in the debugger, there's no errors in the output window?  how did you add AI?  through the wizard?  manually installed packages?  need more info to be helpful.

Comment: @JohnGardner no i have no errors. The project builds fine. If i start with a new mvc project. Install App Insights by right clicking on the solution tree. thats it broken, it will no longer debug using f5

Comment: and there's nothing useful in the F5 output when debugging?  nothing about loading assemblies or anything?  i don't know if i've ever seen this case, but when i have it is usually because a package isn't loading or something is wrong with web.config?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ApplicationInsight causing website to hang at startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874790/applicationinsight-causing-website-to-hang-at-startup)

Comment: thanks @JasonAller it is a duplicate. I did search though i swear!

Comment: Adween, just so I am clear, you get this error only when adding it to an existing project? What happens if you create a new one and click the checkbox to add it in on project creation?

Comment: hey @KenCenerelli, no it does it from the get go too. there is an answer in the other post though, this is a duplicate and i have closed it. thanks anyway